# Html elements hides on script execution

Tags: javascript, local-storage, primes, web-worker, web-sql

I'm working on solution to find prime numbers and everything is ok except one issue. It stops on i == 373 && j == 15 in web worker file. My Html page disapears and execution can be resumed after reloading page. But input params are the same(they are stored in localStorage) and it makes me crazy. After some time execution again stops and html elements disapears. Also js in console not working too. No errors are handeled.I'm at loss. Thank you.

**MAIN.JS**

```
    var db = openDatabase("primeNumbers", "0.1", "Prime numbers db", 200000);
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
      tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS primeNumbers (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, value INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE)", [], null, null);
    });
    var settings = {};
    prepareData();

    $(document).ready( function() {
      $('#start_button').click( function() {
        toggleButton();
      });
      $('#show_table_button').click(function() {
        showTableButton();
      });
      $('#show_canvas_image_button').click(function() {
        showCanvas();
      });
    });

    //check if db can be used
    if(!db){alert("Failed to connect to database.");}

    var currNumber = 2;
    var work;

    var worker = new Worker('js/worker.js');//(blobURL);

    //worker event listener
    worker.onmessage = function(event) {
      (event.data != undefined) && (settings.bFlag = true);
      finder(true);
    };

function finder(again) {
  if(settings.j == 14 && settings.i == 373) {
    console.log('70');
  };
  if(again) {
    if ( settings.bFlag ){
      settings.j = 0;
      if ( settings.iShag == 3 ){
        settings.i+=4;
        settings.iShag = 0;
      } else {
        settings.i+=2;
        settings.iShag++;
      };
      iSquare = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(settings.i));
      settings.bFlag = false;
    };
    settings.j++;
  };
  storeTempData();
  work && worker.postMessage('{\"i\":\"'+settings.i+'\",\"j\":\"'+settings.j+'\"}');
};

function toggleButton() {
  btn = $('#start_button');
  if(btn.text() != 'pause_calculations') {
    btn.text('pause_calculations');
    work = true;
    finder(false);
  } else {
    btn.text('resume_calculations');
    work = false;
  };
};

// table with data
function showTableButton() {
  //TODO: check if we can use this as parameter to function
  btn = $('#show_table_button');
  if(btn.text() == 'show_calculated_data') {
    btn.text('reload_table');
    renderTable();
  } else {
    //TODO: implement it renderTable();
  };
};

var table_data;

function renderTable() {
  getBlockOfDataFromDb( function() {
    $('#table_with_results').jqGrid({
      datatype: 'local',
      data: table_data,
      height: 230,
      width: 350,
      colNames: ['id', 'value'],
      colModel: [
        { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 20, sorttype: 'int', align: 'right' },
        { name: 'value', index: 'value', width: 20, sorttype: 'int', align: 'right'}
      ],
      multiselect: false,
      caption: 'Prime numbers from db',
      rowNum: 10,
      pager: 'table_pager',
      pagination: true,
      gridview: true,
      edit:false,
      add:false,
      del:false
    });
  });
};

function getBlockOfDataFromDb(callback) {
  var res = [];
 db.transaction(function(tx) {
   tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM primeNumbers', [], function(tx, result) { 
     result_length = result.rows.length;
     for(var i = 0; i < result_length; i++) {
       var json_obj = { id: result.rows.item(i).id, value: result.rows.item(i).value };
       res.push(json_obj);
     };
     table_data = res;
    callback();
   });
 });
};

Array.prototype.contains = function(k) {
    for(var p in this)
        if(this[p] === k)
            return true;
    return false;
};

function showCanvas() {
  var primeArray = [];
  var edge;
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM primeNumbers', [], function(tx, result) { 
      result_length = result.rows.length;
      for(var i = 0; i < result_length; i++) {
        primeArray.push(parseInt(result.rows.item(i).value));
      };
      edge = parseInt(Math.sqrt(Math.max.apply(Math, primeArray))) + 1;

      canv_div = $('#canvas_div');
      $('<canvas width="'+edge+'" height="'+edge+'" id="canvas_elem"></canvas>').appendTo(canv_div);
      canv = $('#canvas_elem')[0];
      var context = canv.getContext('2d');
      var imgd = context.createImageData(edge,edge);
      var pix = imgd.data;
      var iter = 0;
      for (var i = 0; n = pix.length, i < n; i += 4) {
        pix[i] = 0;
        if(primeArray.contains(iter)) {
          pix[i+3] = 255;
        } else {
          pix[i+3] = 50;
        };
        iter++;
      }
      context.putImageData(imgd, 0,0);
    });
  });
};

function prepareData() {

  var ls = localStorage;

  if(ls.getItem('bFlag') && ls.getItem('i') && ls.getItem('j') && ls.getItem('iShag')) {
    settings.bFlag = (ls.getItem('bFlag') === 'true');
    settings.i     = parseInt(ls.getItem('i'));
    settings.j     = parseInt(ls.getItem('j'));
    settings.iShag = parseInt(ls.getItem('iShag'));
  } else {
    settings.i     = 7;
    settings.j     = 1;
    settings.iShag = 0;
    settings.bFlag = false;
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO primeNumbers (value) SELECT 2 AS value UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 5');
    });
  };
};
function storeTempData() {
  localStorage.setItem('i'     , settings.i);
  localStorage.setItem('j'     , settings.j);
  localStorage.setItem('bFlag' , settings.bFlag);
  localStorage.setItem('iShag' , settings.iShag);
};
```

and also my **WORKER.JS**

```
onmessage = function(event) {
  data = JSON.parse(event.data);
  i = parseInt(data['i']);
  j = parseInt(data['j']);
  iSquare = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(i));
  run();
};
function run() {
  var db = openDatabase("primeNumbers", "0.1", "Prime numbers db", 200000);
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    if(i == 373 && j == 15) {
      1+1;
    };
    tx.executeSql('SELECT value FROM primeNumbers WHERE id='+(j+1), [], function(tx, result) {
      val = parseInt(result.rows.item(0)['value']);
      if ( i % val == 0 ){
        self.postMessage('bFlag');
      } else if (j >= iSquare) {
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
          tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO primeNumbers (value) VALUES ('+i+')', [], function() {
            self.postMessage('bFlag');
          });
        });
      } else {
        self.postMessage();
      };
    },
    function(tx, error) {
      self.postMessage('Error processing SQL: ' + error);
    });
  }, function(error) {
    self.postMessage('Error processing Transaction: ' + error)
  });
};
```

I will be happy in any ideas.
Perhaps smb know how to catch errors or what i need to find in chrome profiler.
I wrote a video with the proces. [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FUf2kjDEBLs&feature=youtu.be)

Answer (score 0):

The issue resolved. I've moved SELECT statment from worker to main file. I think that problem was in error handling in worker, because it was a lot of errors from db when i tried to select nonexistent value(it needs by algorithm).